# Where can I see a contributors phone number and email?

Tags: contribution-page

On the contribution page, there is space for the visitor to enter their phone number and email (we need this information).

When I look at the contributions made, this information is not view-able or there at all. I tried to go into the management page for the contribution page to edit the settings, although there is nothing I can find to help me solve this issue. [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the contact name ie. 'From' on the form shown on your screen shot it will take you to the contact summary page of the contact where you will get to see all the details of the contact stored for it. If you still can't see the details than your user might not have required permission to view contact details

Comment: Yes, this. The contribution pop-up is only going to show you the actual contribution details, not any of the contact's profile information.

Comment: This is what you wanted?